# unable to fit three images inside their grid container

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I can't figure out how to solve this problem:

```css
.picture-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 36%; 
  width: 90%;
  left: 5%;
  
  border: 5px dashed red;
}

.three-image-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  gap: 20px;
}

.img-frame-container {

}


.img-frame {
  border: 5px solid #e8e8e8;
  box-shadow: 1px 7px 20px 9px rgb(0 0 0 / 75%);
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #dfe4ea;
  user-select: none;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scale-container">

<div class="picture-container">
  <div class="three-image-container">
    <div class="img-frame-container">
      <img class="img-frame" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4876243/pexels-photo-4876243.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
    </div>
    <div class="img-frame-container">
      <img class="img-frame" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/9646282/pexels-photo-9646282.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
    </div>
    <div class="img-frame-container">
      <img class="img-frame" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1386454/pexels-photo-1386454.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

I want all those images and their frames to have the exact same `width` and `height` as you see above, but I want them to fit into the `picture-container` width and height.

Now with fixed dimensions the third image exceeds the right border of the `picture-container`.

How can I have all three frames inside the container?

I thought that using this:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
```

would do what I want, but it seems that it doesn't work if I use an image inside the frames!

Note that the frames should be in the same sizes and did not exceed the container size and I like to be able to have more or less frames so we may need some sort of max-width or something.

Comment: you are forcing the image width to 250px. Add `max-width:100%` on the `.img-frame`. Also the `gap` property should be `grid-gap`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forcing the image width to 250px.
I added `max-width:100%` on the `.img-frame` and `box-sizing: border-box` to make sure the width of the items include the borders.

[Read more on the box-sizing property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Also the `gap` property should be `grid-gap`

```css
.picture-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 36%; 
  width: 90%;
  left: 5%;
  border: 5px dashed red;
}

.three-image-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 20px; /* this was fixed */
}

.img-frame-container {

}


.img-frame {
  border: 5px solid #e8e8e8;
  box-shadow: 1px 7px 20px 9px rgb(0 0 0 / 75%);
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #dfe4ea;
  user-select: none;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  /* these 2 lines were added */
  max-width: 100%; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="scale-container">

<div class="picture-container">
  <div class="three-image-container">
    <div class="img-frame-container">
      <img class="img-frame" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4876243/pexels-photo-4876243.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
    </div>
    <div class="img-frame-container">
      <img class="img-frame" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/9646282/pexels-photo-9646282.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
    </div>
    <div class="img-frame-container">
      <img class="img-frame" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1386454/pexels-photo-1386454.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: BRILIENT.......and still simple ...

Answer (score 1):

Changed the `display` from `grid` to `flex` and used relative values in width (`%`, value depend on container or the window size ) instead of absolute values (`px`, value doesn't depend on container or the window size).

Use `*{box-sizing: border-box}` so that `border` `padding` don't take extra space and instead content space is utilized making less overflow when `size` equals to `screen width`

[See here more about `box-sizing`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.picture-container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 5px dashed red;
}

.three-image-container {
  display: flex;
}

.img-frame-container {
  width: 100%;
  padding:0 10px;
}

.img-frame {
  border: 5px solid #e8e8e8;
  box-shadow: 1px 7px 20px 9px rgb(0 0 0 / 75%);
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #dfe4ea;
  user-select: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  object-fit: fill;
}
```

```html
<div class="scale-container">

  <div class="picture-container">
    <div class="three-image-container">
      <div class="img-frame-container">
        <img class="img-frame" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/4876243/pexels-photo-4876243.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
      </div>
      <div class="img-frame-container">
        <img class="img-frame" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/9646282/pexels-photo-9646282.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
      </div>
      <div class="img-frame-container">
        <img class="img-frame" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1386454/pexels-photo-1386454.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: % vs px is not "soft code vs hard code". When something is hard coded it is using an absolute fixed value rather than a relative or dynamic value; you should use that terminology instead (relative vs absolute) when talking about % vs px.

Comment: Thanks @TylerH , changed that to relative/absolute . When do hard and soft code be used

Comment: `hard coded` means that it is a piece of code that later on can not be changed. HTML wise it is evry limited what actually is hard-coded. The closest thing to it would be email-templates.

Comment: @Rana soft code is not really a term at all; hard code is used in cases where it fits the context as I mentioned in my first comment (e.g. when you manually write some code or value rather than have that value be calculated dynamically from some source)

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `width: 90%;` from `.picture-container`.

It's making that div take up 90% of the width of the parent (which itself fills the window) regardless of its own contents.

Comment: that is not the issue in this case.

Comment: Yet I tested it and it fixed the problem.

Comment: and what happens when you make the screen width lower than 750px ? those images have a fixed width of 250px; just removing the 90% width will not fix the problem

Comment: The problem in the first place was not that 3*250 may exceed some screen widths. That's obvious, but the OP didn’t bring it up. They asked about the images overflowing the container with the border.

I went with the assumption that if they gave fixed widths to certain elements, that may be important and I’ll try to preserve it. You’re assuming it’s unimportant. Since the OP didn’t specify, they’re both valid approaches. (Actually the question's been edited multiple times since I first read it. It’s still not 100% clear but was originally more vague).